# Angular Formly - parse directive in wrapper

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have a field set up as:

```
{type: 'check', key: 'agreeTC', 
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'I agree to the promotional <a ui-sref="terms">Terms & Conditions</a>'}}
```

In order to get the HTML to render I have this in my wrapper:

```
<span ng-bind-html="to.label"></span>
```

But the ui-router directive ui-sref is not being detected. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Please post a plunker of your code in action so people can help debug

Comment: `ng-bind-html` just sets the HTML, it does not `$compile`, which is what you'd need to get directives working

Comment: Just as @NewDev said, you'll want to use `$compile`. You can accomplish this by adding a `controller` to your `type` or your `field` and inject `$compile` and use that to compile the label. Perhaps a better approach would be to make a custom directive which would do this for you and pass the `to.label` to that. Good luck!